# Why can't cmake find boost?

Tags: c++, boost, cmake, open-source

I'm trying to build SuperTux using this [instruction](https://github.com/SuperTux/supertux/blob/master/INSTALL.md#installing-under-windows-using-cmake-and-visual-studio):

But CMake 3.11 fails

```
D:\OpenSourceProjects\SuperTux\supertux\build>cmake ..
CMake Deprecation Warning at CMakeLists.txt:49 (CMAKE_POLICY):
  The OLD behavior for policy CMP0043 will be removed from a future version
  of CMake.

  The cmake-policies(7) manual explains that the OLD behaviors of all
  policies are deprecated and that a policy should be set to OLD only under
  specific short-term circumstances.  Projects should be ported to the NEW
  behavior and not rely on setting a policy to OLD.


CMake Warning at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.11/Modules/FindBoost.cmake
:564 (message):
  Imported targets and dependency information not available for Boost version
  (all versions older than 1.33)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.11/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:903 (_Boost_CO
MPONENT_DEPENDENCIES)
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.11/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1571 (_Boost_M
ISSING_DEPENDENCIES)
  CMakeLists.txt:125 (FIND_PACKAGE)


CMake Warning at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.11/Modules/FindBoost.cmake
:564 (message):
  Imported targets and dependency information not available for Boost version
  (all versions older than 1.33)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.11/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:903 (_Boost_CO
MPONENT_DEPENDENCIES)
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.11/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1571 (_Boost_M
ISSING_DEPENDENCIES)
  CMakeLists.txt:125 (FIND_PACKAGE)


CMake Warning at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.11/Modules/FindBoost.cmake
:564 (message):
  Imported targets and dependency information not available for Boost version
  (all versions older than 1.33)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.11/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:903 (_Boost_CO
MPONENT_DEPENDENCIES)
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.11/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1571 (_Boost_M
ISSING_DEPENDENCIES)
  CMakeLists.txt:125 (FIND_PACKAGE)


CMake Warning at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.11/Modules/FindBoost.cmake
:564 (message):
  Imported targets and dependency information not available for Boost version
  (all versions older than 1.33)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.11/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:903 (_Boost_CO
MPONENT_DEPENDENCIES)
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.11/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1571 (_Boost_M
ISSING_DEPENDENCIES)
  CMakeLists.txt:125 (FIND_PACKAGE)


CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.11/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1
956 (message):
  Unable to find the requested Boost libraries.

  Unable to find the Boost header files.  Please set BOOST_ROOT to the root
  directory containing Boost or BOOST_INCLUDEDIR to the directory containing
  Boost's headers.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:125 (FIND_PACKAGE)


CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.11/Modules/FindPackageHandle
StandardArgs.cmake:137 (message):
  Could NOT find OpenAL (missing: OPENAL_LIBRARY OPENAL_INCLUDE_DIR)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.11/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.
cmake:378 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.11/Modules/FindOpenAL.cmake:96 (FIND_PACK
AGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)
  CMakeLists.txt:171 (FIND_PACKAGE)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "D:/OpenSourceProjects/SuperTux/supertux/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.l
og".
```

I'm trying to specify BOOST_INCLUDEDIR like

```
SET(BOOST_INCLUDEDIR, "/dependencies64/include/boost")
```

but nothing changes. In CMakeOutput.log Visual studio say that building was complete. What i do wrong?

Comment: Judging by the instructions you likely took a wrong turn at step #2. Check that your setup really truly matches those instructions. Alternatively experiment with `-DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=` to help find boost.

Comment: Im tried to put "dependencies64" folder in root of project, and in "src" folder, also i tried rename "depencies" folder and put in root of project and in "src". Nothing changes.

"-DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=" requires folder with "CMakeList.txt". This file contains only root of project, im trying to run cmake with "-DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=D:\OpenSourceProjects\SuperTux\supertux" but result is the same

Comment: *CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH* **doesn't require** folder with `CMakeLists.txt`. Instead it should contain **installation prefix** of the (Boost) package. Usually, this prefix has subfolders like `include/` and `libs/`.